# I am not able to set the path, where to save my project. It is giving some errors

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am not able to set the path, where to save my project. It is giving some error. Can anyone help me with what the issue is?

Comment: Please share more details, like which path you were trying to set, which Deveco studio, did you set up your project in AGC yet?  etc..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a non-empty directory in the newly created project, as shown in the following figure:

[image]

If the problem persists, pls provide more detail error information for us to check.